# atk4 advanced crud?

Tags: mysql, crud, atk4

I have the following tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `product`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `productName` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `s7location` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `pages`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `productID` INT NULL ,
  `pageName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `isBlank` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  `pageOrder` INT(11) NULL ,
  `s7page` INT(11) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `productID` (`productID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `productID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productID` )
    REFERENCES `product` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `field`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `field` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `pagesID` INT NULL ,
  `fieldName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `fieldType` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `fieldDefaultValue` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `id` (`pagesID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `pagesID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pagesID` )
    REFERENCES `pages` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have gotten CRUD to work on the 'product' table.

```
//addproduct.php
class page_addproduct extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $crud=$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Product');

    }
}
```

This works.  but I need to get it so that when a new product is created it basically allows me to add new rows into the pages and field tables.

For example, the products in the tables are a print product(like a greeting card) that has multiple pages to render.  Page 1 may have 2 text fields that can be customized, page 2 may have 3 text fields, a slider to define text size, and a drop down list to pick a color, and page 3 may have five text fields that can all be customized.  All three pages (and all form elements, 12 in this example) are associated with 1 product.

So when I create the product, could i add a button to create a page for that product, then within the page i can add a button to add a new form element field?

I'm still somewhat new to this, so my db structure may not be ideal.  i'd appreciate any suggestions and feedback!  Could someone point me toward some information, tutorials, documentation, ideas, suggestions, on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can't add page unless you have an existing product. We normally solve that problem with a state field. Add this into your product model:

```
$this->addField('state')->enum(array('active','draft'))->defaultValue('draft');
```

also create it in SQL. Also it's generally good to describe relations, so add this into your product model:

```
$this->hasMany('Page','productID');
```

Next you will need to change the action when a new record is added. You can do that easily by extending crud class:

```
class MyCRUD extends CRUD {
    function formSubmitSuccess(){
        if($_GET['id']) return parent::formSubmitSuccess(); // edit ->save

        // add ->save handled here
        $this->js()->univ()->location($this->api->url('./details',
          array('id'=>$this->form->model->id)))->execute();
    }
}
```

and replacing add('CRUD') with add('MyCRUD'). Next if you are placing CRUD on page "mypage" you will need to create "mypage/details". After successfully saving new product, your new method will redirect user to this new page and it will pass along the productID too.

On this new page, you should have

```
$m=$this->add('Model_Product')->load($_GET['id']); // makes sure ID is valid
$this->api->stickyGET('id');  // configures page to carry id= value along
$crud=$this->add('CRUD');
$crud->setModel($m->ref('Page'));
```

This will display CRUD here which will automatically edit pages of that particular product. The only thing you miss now is a back button.

```
if($crud->grid){
    if($crud->grid->addButton('Save')->isClicked()){
        // AJAX action on button click

        $m->set('status','active')->save(); // update status of current product
        $this->js()->univ()->location($this->api->url('..'))->execute();
        // redirect back to parent page
    }

    // You might want a cancel button too
    $crud->grid->addButton('Cacel')->js('click')
         ->univ()->location($this->api->url('..'));

    // no AJAX, simple javascript action.
}
```

To finish everything nicely, go back to your original page and add a condition. You don't have to create new model, unless you want, can be like this:

```
// on my page
$this->add('MyCRUD')->setModel('Product')->addCondition('state','active');
```

This way your main CRUD won't display records which are incomplete. Your database may accumulate draft records which you can delete once in a while. If anything here does not work, publish your project on Github and share it with our Agile Toolkit development group, some of us would certainly implement this for you.

BONUS:

You might want how should you edit existing product pages? Easiest would be to have expander in the main crud's grid:

```
$crud=$this->add('MyCRUD');
$crud->setModel('Product')->addCondition('state','active');
$crud->addColumn('expander','details'); // will expand into page mypage/details and will automatically pass ID.
```

This solution is not 100% ideal, but given the character of the WEB applications and their reliance on SQL that's a great way to manage your data.

Comment: well i went through your post and i can't get it to work.  here is the github link [link](https://github.com/thindery/builder.git).  after i click submit to add a product, the product gets added to the db.. but this error is returned:

Comment: Exception_Logic

Method is not defined for this object


Additional information:

Raised by object: Object Model_Product(sample_project_addproduct_details_model_product)
class: Model_Product
method: refModel
arguments: Array ( [0] => Pages )

Comment: that's just "ref" there, sorry. fixed now.